# Magento salesrule override not working

Tags: magento-1.9, rules

I want to override the SalesRule model for my custom module, but it already used in another third party module. But the problem is my override is loading always first.

And the third party module's override is stopped because of mine.

So what I have done for solution, added the depends tag in the module declarations.

```
<codePool>local</codePool>
<depends>
      <RandW_RewardPoint/>
</depends>
```

In my module **config.xml**

```
<salesrule>
    <rewrite>
        <validator>Toy_Gift_Model_Validator</validator>
    </rewrite>
</salesrule>
```

Third party config.xml

```
<salesrule>
    <rewrite>
        <validator>RandW_RewardPoint_Model_Validator</validator>
    </rewrite>
</salesrule>
```

And in my **Validator.php**

```
class Toy_Gift_Model_Validator extends RandW_RewardPoint_Model_Validator  {
```

But its not working as expected, still always working from my module. My idea is both should work. Please give me a solution.